# How to keep width and height of an image when converting to PDF? [FPDF]

Tags: php, fpdf

I have implemented this library [FPDF], to convert images to PDF.

But I want the image converted to PDF to keep its height and width.

I have the following code...

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    require("fpdf.php");

    $image = "my_image.jpg";
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image($image/*80 ,22, 35 , 38,*/ "jpg");
    $pdf->Output("convert.pdf","F");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> list($x1, $y1) = getimagesize($image);
> $pdf->Image($image,$x1,$y1,0,0));

check if this solution suits you
and remember
w
Width of the image in the page. There are three cases:
If the value is positive, it represents the width in user unit
If the value is negative, the absolute value represents the horizontal resolution in dpi
If the value is not specified or equal to zero, it is automatically calculated
h
Height of the image in the page. There are three cases:
If the value is positive, it represents the height in user unit
If the value is negative, the absolute value represents the vertical resolution in dpi
If the value is not specified or equal to zero, it is automatically calculated

```
download this image http://www.fpdf.org/logo.gif



<?php
    require("fpdf.php");

    $image = "logo.gif";
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $image );
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image($image, 0, 0 , $width, $height);
    $pdf->Output("convert.pdf","F");
?>
```

this should generate a pdf with the image in its original width and height

Comment: Do you have the source of that information?

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

Comment: I still do not understand

Comment: it is not possible to add any image to pdf. If the image is larger than the working area of the PDF - something must happen - reducing the size of the image, cutting off a piece of the image. If the image is smaller than the working area of the PDF and its DPI is 96 - then the image should keep its original size

Comment: The sheet size of the PDF I want is A4. If an image is larger, I want it to automatically scale to the A4 size of the PDF. How could I do that?

Comment: About the answer... It did not work, the image is displayed with a tremendous zoom.

Comment: use this https://gist.github.com/benshimmin/4088493 function resizeToFit auto scale image to pdf

Comment: @WiatroBosy Thank you very much, everything seems to work fine for now.